# How to generate Code Analysis report in Azure DevOps for a .NET 5.0 Project?

Tags: azure-devops, code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis

I am new to code quality analysis and I have a .NET 5.0 Project. Following the instructions in these two articles [Overview of .NET source code analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/roslyn-analyzers-overview?view=vs-2019) and [Overview of source code analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/overview), I had added the following settings to the project file.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AnalysisLevel>latest</AnalysisLevel>
    <EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>true</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>
    <RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>true</RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>
    <EnableNETAnalyzers>true</EnableNETAnalyzers>
    <CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors>false</CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

This looks fine as I build the project.

Now I want to get a report when I execute my Azure DevOps build pipeline.

Is there any specific Azure DevOps task for this. I found [Roslyn Analyzers build task](https://secdevtools.azurewebsites.net/helpRoslynAnalyzers.html),

But so far I could not find a way to add this to the pipeline. Looks like this task is a part of [Microsoft Security Code Analysis Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/develop/security-code-analysis-overview/). Furthermore, I may have [to purchase this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/develop/security-code-analysis-onboard#interested-in-purchasing-the-microsoft-security-code-analysis-extension).

All I am looking for is a simple Azure DevOps task which can show me the the code quality analysis report(not code coverage). If there is there one, please suggest.

Comment: AFAIK, Effective March 1, 2022, the Microsoft Security Code Analysis (MSCA) extension will be retired. You could consider the SonarQube for code quality, which looked fairly easily to integrate with a pipeline.

Comment: What do you want to do with that report? If you want the build to fail on warnings, just set `<TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>`.